# JQuery form API throwing the error Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform, jqueryform

I'm using jquery and jquery form API for image upload with PHP,
when I use callback anonymous functions for jquery form API it keep throwing me this error on every anonymous function,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

I can't even use any other jquery function with this code also,
maybe if I fix this error it'll work,

my code is

```js
$(function() {
  // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
  $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
    beforeSend: function() {
      alert('before send');
      $('#form-asset-create').validate();
    },
    uploadProgress: function() {},
    success: function() {},
    compile: function() {}
  });
  $(".card").hide();
});
```

Comment: There's an error in your syntax, you shouldn't use `function ()` as first parameter of `ajaxForm`. If you use a function the you use statements inside, `beforeSend: function() {...` is not a statement is part of an object.

Comment: actually i took that syntax from JQuery form API documentation page only :o

Comment: Could you provide link? What you've got there is no valid javascript. It can't even be parsed.

Comment: not complete function, like documentation of beforeSend: and all, and i tried to use it,

Comment: You had an error copying, your code is almost ok, just remove `function ()` after `ajaxForm(` and it should work. See mplungjan answer. What you pass as parameter to that function is `function() { beforeSend: ... }` and that's what does not make sense. To be valid js either you pass a function or an object, you're giving it a function with invalid js code inside. And even if you correct the code inside the function, it'd be valid js but not functional code since `ajaxForm(` needs an object as parameter not a function.

Comment: oh thanks, it worked.!! :D

Comment: No prob fellow dev.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135200/discussion-between-rak-code-and-mark-e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass object literal with config options to `ajaxForm` instead of a function.

```js
$(function() {
  // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
      alert('before send');
      $('#form-asset-create').validate();
    },
    uploadProgress: function() {},
    success: function() {},
    compile: function() {}
  });
  $(".card").hide();
});
```

Comment: i wnat to show progress of uploading image, for that i need those functions

Comment: that card is progress bar, befor calling any function

Comment: The card does not matter. The issue is you passing a function to ajaxForm instead of an object - you have `$('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {...});` but need `$('#myForm').ajaxForm({ ... });`